# Wobble Elastic Animation in Html

Tags: javascript, html, animation, gsap

Take a look at this Dribble

https://dribbble.com/shots/2149937-Day-6-Currency-Status-Rebound

There is a green bar that comes in at the end of the animation with a cool effect. I want to do that in html.

Any advice on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Blindman67 has given a good link. but it is very restrictive and not expandable.

but i found some other cool way.

update svg path attribute with JavaScript and animate it with [dynamic.js](http://dynamicsjs.com/)

```
<svg>
  <path fill="#3F51B5" d="M0,0 L320,0 320,160Q160,160 0,160"></path>
</svg>
```

can easily update the "d" attribute with jQuery or JavaScript

check this fiddle below.. its built with vuejs but its a good example.
http://jsfiddle.net/yyx990803/2eg8kbyk/light/

hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

Yes possible. Here is one example [Elastic SVG](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/12/15/elastic-svg-elements/) and there are plenty of other examples and libraries available to create these types of FXs using SVG or Canvas elements and javascript.