# How is this elastic effect achieved?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

From this website: http://waaark.com/ how is the elastic effect of the block elements achieved when you mouse past them? for example the pink and the blue block.

Comment: they use a [Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Canvas) in the background to draw the effect. But you can also use svg for this [Wobble Elastic Animation in Html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33518430)

Comment: https://codepen.io/waaark/pen/ENRvvq

Answer (score 0):

http://tympanus.net/Development/ElasticSVGElements/ <- this may give you a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at that page with Chrome's built in Inspector, there's a `<canvas>` tag being used to render the effect. I'd imagine they are looking at a mousemove event and rendering to the canvas based on that.  You could de-minify this JS file to work out exactly how they're doing it.  http://waaark.com/wp-content/cache/min/1/e36c0a27f3c428762918cb2a4338507c.js